# Function lfit in numerical recipes, providing a test function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am trying to fit collected data to a polynomial equation and I found the `lfit` function from Numerical Recipes. I only have access to the second edition, so am using that.

I have read about the `lfit` function and its parameters, one of which is a function pointer, given in the documentation as

```
void (*funcs)(float, float [], int))
```

with the help

> The user supplies a routine funcs(x,afunc,ma) that returns the ma basis functions evaluated at x = x in the array afunc[1..ma].

I am struggling to understand how this `lfit` function works. An example function I found is given below:

```
void fpoly(float x, float p[], int np)
/*Fitting routine for a polynomial of degree np-1, with coeﬃcients in the array p[1..np].*/
{
    int j;
    p[1]=1.0;
    for (j=2;j<=np;j++)
        p[j]=p[j-1]*x;
}
```

When I run through the source code for the `lfit` function in gdb I can see no reference to the `funcs` pointer. When I try and fit a simple data set with the function, I get the following error message.

> ```
> Numerical Recipes run-time error...
> gaussj: Singular Matrix
> ...now exiting to system...
> ```

Clearly somehow a matrix is getting defined with all zeroes.

I am going to involve this function fitting in a large loop so using another language is not really an option. Hence why I am planning on using C/C++.

For reference, the test program is given here:

```
int main()
{

    float x[5] = {0., 0., 1., 2., 3.};
    float y[5] = {0., 0., 1.2, 3.9, 7.5};
    float sig[5] = {1., 1., 1., 1., 1.};

    int ndat = 4;
    int ma = 4; /* parameters in equation */
    float a[5] = {1, 1, 1, 0.1, 1.5};
    int ia[5] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    float **covar = matrix(1, ma, 1, ma);

    float chisq = 0;

    lfit(x,y,sig,ndat,a,ia,ma,covar,&chisq,fpoly);

    printf("%f\n", chisq);  
    free_matrix(covar, 1, ma, 1, ma);


    return 0;
}
```

Also confusing the issue, all the Numerical Recipes functions are 1 array-indexed so if anyone has corrections to my array declarations let me know also!

Cheers

**edit:** Ok just discovered the problem to this.

When copying the numerical recipes code, I accidentally commented out some real code thinking it was just a comment. I no longer get the singular value error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since switched to the 3rd edition of NR which has a more understandable routine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the *lfit* function but could you please add some *fprintf* to *stderr* at the beginning of the *fpoly* function and another at the end of the function to see where it actually crashes or if the parameters received are correct/or valid?

Sorry if this is not helpful but I assume that *lfit* function is working well and the problem is in the *fpoly* function.